# What's the bese encoding for csv to be imported by Microsoft excel?

Tags: excel, encoding, csv

Microsoft Excel 2000 does not import csv encoded in UTF-8 properly. Which encoding should I used if unicode characters (for example, English + Chinese + Japanese) are embedded in the CSV? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you probably want UTF16LE